# How to debug TCP Connection Refused?

Tags: linux, debugging, tcp, connection

I have a simple(ish) webapp benchmark setup:

LoadGenerator -> Apache -> WebApp

When I run my benchmarks with a few thousand test users...evertything works as expected.

However, when I increase the number of test users to around 14k...my Apache server starts to refuse *some* connections to my LoadGenerator. CPU utilization is nowhere near capacity...and there doesnt seem to be any dropped connections from Apache to my WebApp.

I believe I am running out of some resource on my Apache server, but I cant tell what? I thought it could be ports...but my connections arent quite high enough for that I believe.

Next I tried looking at tcpdump info...but I really didnt see anyhting interesting. Though honestly, I just opened up the dump in Wireshark and looked for big red marks.

Is there a way to to have the kernel output error messages in the hopse that I might see something that tells me whats happening. In a perfect world, I would see an error message like "ERROR: not enough X for number of connections".

Any other tips you might recommend to see why my LoadGenerator keeps hitting connction refused?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable the [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) module and see how many workers are used etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google 'TIME_WAIT' - you are probably running out of available sockets.

Comment: Initially, I had tens of thousands of TIME_WAITS, then I turned on KeepAlive...and almost all my TIME_WAITS went away. Now I have 7k or 8K ESTABLISHED connections....but the problem persists. So that wasnt it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking out of resource then please try

```
ulimit -a
```

This will show resource limit of your process.
The output is something like below

```
  core file size (blocks)   1000000
  data seg size (kbytes)    unlimited
  file size (blocks)            unlimited
  max memory size (kbytes)  unlimited
  stack size (kbytes)           8192
  cpu time (seconds)            unlimited
  max user processes            unlimited  (1)
  pipe size (512 bytes)         8
  open files                    1024
  virtual memory (kbytes)   2105343
```

here you check open files. Which describe limit of fd(including socket, pipe, file, ...) allow to open by linux.

You can change this by ulimit -n

Make sure you have same problem. Otherwise this is not useful.

ulimit ref: http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

Comment: I checked ulimit, mostly to see what my open file descriptor limit...since that was my initial suspect. I was way under. I sort of get the feeling it could be some esoteric tcp parameter....one that would need to be tuned for over 400 connections per second.